# Area discrepancy between geometry and mask

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm masking land cover data and clipping it to a geometry. Then I'm calculating the masked area.

When comparing the area of the mask vs the area of the geometry I'm getting a discrepancy. Here are the areas based on the code below:

- Non forest area: `13,281.51`
- geometry area: `13,277.97`

Why is that?

Code:

```js
Map.centerObject(geometry);
var FNF = ee.ImageCollection('JAXA/ALOS/PALSAR/YEARLY/FNF4')
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01')
  .mosaic()
  
var nonForest = ee.Image(1).mask(FNF.select('fnf').eq(3))

var nonForestArea = nonForest.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())
  .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.sum(), geometry, 25)
  .get('constant')
  
print('Non forest area', nonForestArea)
print('geometry area',geometry.area({maxError: 1 }))


var fnfVis = { min: 1, max: 4, palette: ['00b200', '83ef62', 'ffff99', '0000ff'] };
Map.addLayer(FNF, fnfVis, 'Land Cover');
var nonForestVis = { min: 1, max: 1, palette: ['ffff99'] };
Map.addLayer(nonForest, nonForestVis, 'non forest');
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/80d6aee39422f776b5da235328490e6c